# Evaluate code fragment is stuck/disabled in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

### Problem

I am running a project using a `tomcat` configuration in IntelliJ.
The Evaluate Expression and Evaluate Code Fragment dialog is stuck in that I cannot type within the box. The break points work normally though.

This is the first time I am seeing this behavior.

### Update

I noticed the focus is stuck on the project pane and sometimes a `search for:` box appears.

Comment: What kind of plugins do you have enabled? IdeaVim is usually the culprit of textboxes not responding

Comment: @Jeeter it is a completely new installation. Today it's not doing it anymore strange.

Comment: Take a look at "Event Log" window and/or Intellij log file (<USER_HOME>/.IntellijIDEA<version>/system/log/idea.log)  It probably contains more details about what's going wrong.